# Strange Behavior in Barchart LabelingFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, charts

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

[`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart.html) formatting algorithm make me loose some time today in V10.
Now, [`LabelingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LabelingFunction.html) does not work beyond some number of Labels. See example:

```
RandomSeed[1]
barchart[n_]:=
    BarChart[RandomInteger[10,{n,3}]
            ,LabelingFunction->(Placed[#1,Center]&)
            ,AspectRatio->0.2,ImageSize->700
            ,ChartLayout->"Percentile"
    ]

barchart[33]
barchart[34]
```

[image]

After 33, labels disappear!

Which magic parameter can I change to get my labels back? The problem is the same in V10.0.0 for Mac and Win.

I wrote to support. If I get some clue I'll post here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior was corrected in Mathematica 10.0.1.

Using the same example:

```
    RandomSeed[1]
barchart[n_]:=
    BarChart[RandomInteger[10,{n,3}]
            ,LabelingFunction->(Placed[#1,Center]&)
            ,AspectRatio->0.2,ImageSize->700
            ,ChartLayout->"Percentile"
    ]

barchart[33]
barchart[100]
```

We now have:
[image]

My tks to Wolfram team!

Comment: Note: with `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"` and `"Percentile"` labels are not labeled.

Comment: Thanks for posting this notification.

Comment: @rcollyer `Stacked` and `Percentile` worked nice to me in V10.0.1.

Comment: They'll work, but the zero height bars aren't labeled. Just a warning.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround is just to use multiple bar charts for the data

```
RandomSeed[1];
Clear[barchart];
barchart[n_, partitions_: 1] := Module[
  {m = Ceiling[n/partitions]},
  BarChart[
      #,
      LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &),
      AspectRatio -> 0.2,
      ImageSize -> 700,
      ChartLayout -> "Percentile"] & /@
    Partition[
     Join[
      RandomInteger[10, {n, 3}],
      Table["", {m - 1}]],
     m] //
   Column]

barchart[33]
```

[image]

```
barchart[51, 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The maximum number of labeled bars in Version 10.0.0 seems to be limited to 99 when `LabelingFunction` is used. An alternative work-around is to wrap data with `Labeled`:

```
RandomSeed[1]
barchart2[n_,m_]:=  Module[{dt=RandomInteger[10,{n,m}]},  
       BarChart[Labeled[#,#,Center]&/@#&/@dt,
                AspectRatio->0.2,ImageSize->700,
                ChartLayout->"Percentile" ]]

barchart2[34,3]
```

[image]

```
barchart2[50, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: After a native option to change this behavior, I think this is a good option. +1

Comment: Please reconsider deleting this. This is an effective workaround for pre-v10.0.1.

Comment: @rcollyer, thank you for the vote. just rolled back the delete.