# Limitations on dynamic tooltips in BarChart

Tags: graphics, front-end

I was unsure about the best wording for the title if someone has a better suggestion please edit.

With V10 or V11 on OS X if you evaluate the following (with `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"`):

```
BarChart[{Range[50], Range[50]},ImageSize -> 600]
```

and

```
BarChart[{Range[49], Range[49]},ImageSize -> 600]
```

You will see that the dynamic tooltip and dynamic bar "highlighting" stop when you add the 50th bar. I'm assuming that this might be controlled by a `SystemOption`. Does anyone know what is controlling this behaviour and how this apparent cut-off can be modified?

[image]

Comment: Does `BarChart[{Tooltip/@Range[50],Tooltip/@ Range[50]},  ...]` work as expected?

Comment: perhaps related:  [Strange Behavior in Barchart LabelingFunction](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55222/125)

Comment: @kglr that restores the tooltips but not the bar "highlighting". My interest is not in work arounds but in understanding what is driving the behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is not controlled by any option.  You can construct your own `ChartElementFunction` that has a mouseover effect:

```
BarChart[{Range[50], Range[50]}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 ChartElementFunction -> (Mouseover[
     Rectangle @@ Transpose[#], {EdgeForm[Opacity[0.25]], 
      Rectangle @@ Transpose[#]}] &)]
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. Does that mean the limitation is hard coded into the function code?

Comment: Yes, the cutoff is when the total number of bars is more than 100.

Comment: 100 might seem like plenty but these days with large monitors the cut off seems a bit low. Any reason why this couldn't be controlled in the future by a system option?